# How do I trigger a JS function from a js.erb executed as a callback on an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I know the title reads a bit funky, but this is what I am doing.

I have a link that looks like this, as defined in my `nodes_helper.rb`:

```
    link_to(favorite_node_path(node, node_counter: node_counter), class: "card-favorite-count favorited", method: :post, remote: true,  data: {toggle_href: unfavorite_node_path(node) }) do
      concat(content_tag(:i, "", class: "icon-heart"))
      concat(node.cached_votes_total)
    end
```

That then ultimately, on success, leads to this `/views/nodes/favorites.js.erb` being executed:

```
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").html('<%= favorites_count(@node, @node_counter) %>');
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").append('<%= comments_count(@node) %>');
```

All of that works fine, but what I want to do is add some animation to the class `card-favorite-count` after the link is pressed. Basically, right before the count gets updated.

My animation is defined in my `app/assets/javascripts/nodes.js.coffee` like so:

```
animate_favorite = ($favorite) ->
  $favorite.addClass 'active'
  card = $favorite.parent().parent().parent()
  card_id = card.attr('id')
  setTimeout (->
    $('#' + card_id).find('.card-favorite-count').removeClass 'active'
    return
  ), 1200
  return

$(document).ready ->
  $('.card-favorite-count').click ->
    animate_favorite $(this)
    return
  return
```

The JS version of the above works in a plain old vanilla HTML/JS interface, but I am trying to hook it up with everything else I have going on - hence the conversion to CoffeeScript.

So, how do I call that `animate_favorite` function, from within my `favorite.js.erb`?

**Edit 1**

Per Ryan's suggestion, I tried this in my `favorite.js.erb`:

```
window.animate_favorite($(this));
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").html('<%= favorites_count(@node, @node_counter) %>');
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").append('<%= comments_count(@node) %>');
```

But I get this error in my JS console:

```
window.animate_favorite($(this));
$("#card-1 .card-attr").html('<a class="card-favorite-count favorited" data-method="post" data-remote="true" data-toggle-href="/nodes/2/favorite" href="/nodes/2/unfavorite?node_counter=1" rel="nofollow"><i class="icon-heart"></i>1</a>');
$("#card-1 .card-attr").append('<span class="card-comment-count"><i class="icon-speech-bubble-1"></i>0</span>');

comments.self.js?body=1:5 parsererror
```

**Edit 2**

Per The F's questions, here is my controller for this action:

```
  def favorite
    @node.liked_by current_user
    @node_counter = params[:node_counter]
    current_user.events.create(action: "favorited", eventable: @node)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html{ redirect_to @node }
    end
  end
```

**Edit 3**

When I followed The F's suggestion of putting the JS I want to execute directly into my `favorite.js.erb`, everything works like I want it.

i.e. this is what my `favorite.js.erb` looks like now:

```
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").html('<%= favorites_count(@node, @node_counter) %>');
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").append('<%= comments_count(@node) %>');

$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr .card-favorite-count").addClass('favorited active');
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr .card-favorite-count").removeClass('active');
},1200);
```

So the question is, how do I get this to work within my Rails JS files? Which file do I put this function in so that I can just execute it in my `favorite.js.erb` and not in the declare it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `window.animate_favorite($('.card-favorite-count'));` before inserting the node to the dom?

*updated answer*

Favourably you would return a json response that will hold the html partial you want to include and animate. Then you could listen for a successful ajax call from `nodes.js.coffee` that is triggered by favoriting one of the cards. To achieve this you should do some research on how to make efficient use of javascript. Maybe have a look at [layouts & rendering](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and also [passing data to javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast)

For the moment I would keep the code as it is, as the amount of duplicated code is fairly small and it works the way you intend it to.

favorite.js.erb

```
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").html('<%= favorites_count(@node, @node_counter) %>');
$("#card-<%= @node_counter %> .card-attr").append('<%= comments_count(@node) %>');

$("#card-<%= @node_counter %>").addClass('active');
setTimeout(function() { $("#card-<%= @node_counter %>").removeClass('active'); }, 1200);
```

Also, the js is not very consistent as you're passing `$('.card-favorite-count')` in your click function but wanted to pass your `$('i.icon-heart')` in your favorite.js.erb. You should try to always a similar selector (`card` or `icon`), unless there is a specific reason you were using the two. Sticking with one however, will also simplify your existing jquery.

Comment: Ok so the good news is that once I added your last two lines to my `favorite.js.erb`, I no longer see an error. But it doesn't actually work...i.e. it doesn't actually animate the object. Also, the only Ruby code I see is a debugging message that my app spits out on errors.

Comment: If you see another error, feel free to add it to your question :)

Comment: Ok...so not seeing any more errors, and I cleaned it up per your recommendation. But, when I added that `console.log`, I am not seeing it that variable printed in my console. It doesn't seem to be executing that `console.log` at all, because I just added a regular string as well as the variable and nothing gets printed in my console. So, for whatever reason, it doesn't seem that this function is being called.

Comment: That would mean that you'd get an `undefined function animate_favorite`. If that is the only other place you are using this function, check the second edit of my answer

Comment: I updated the question with the controller code like you asked.

Comment: It would take more work to clean up the current approach, so let's make it work before moving your existing code. Did you try to directly execute your jquery in `favorite.js.erb` (edit2)?

Comment: Ok...when I do it manually and in the `favorite.js.erb`, and select the right selector, it works.

Comment: I updated the question with more details about what works again, so let me know how I can refactor this so it is more DRY. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put them in the window namespace. Try something like this in your `nodes.js.coffee` file:

```
window.animate_favorite = ($favorite) ->
  ...code here...
```

Then, all you need to do to call it (in your `favorite.js.erb` file) is:

```
window.animate_favorite(...element you want to pass in...)
```

Comment: So I don't need to call that on a selector or anything like that?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you need. To have access to the `this`, you need to call it inside of a block. However, no, it works on its own.

Comment: You need to replace `$(this)` with what you actually want to animate.

Comment: Please forgive the seemingly ridiculous questions, but I want to animate the `i.icon-heart` element I have, so I did this: `window.animate_favorite($("i.icon-heart"));` and it still gave a parser error.

Comment: In your `.js.erb` file, or your `.js.coffee` file?

Comment: i was doing it in my `.js.erb`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85047/discussion-between-ryan-k-and-marcamillion).